# What is the way to mutate 2D array with Python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I was expecting that array `a` will be mutated in this Python 3.11 script:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def incr(a):
  for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
  a = mp.Manager().list([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]) 
  
  with mp.Pool(2) as pool:
    pool.map(incr, [a[0], a[1]])

  print(a)
```

equivalent to:

```
  a = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]   
  incr(a[0])
  incr(a[1])
```

but the result is:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
```

How to mutate each row by a different process?

Comment: You should read and understand the following: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#proxy-objects
Note, you do not have a 2D array, you have a list. That lists contains other lists. The manager makes sure that *mutations to the object being managed get reflected*. But you actually aren't involving the proxied object anymore.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, there's a good chance you're going about it wrong. Having multiple processes mutating an object is should be a last resort.  As much as possible, this should be avoided.

Comment: @FrankYellin In my case there is no data race. Each process mutates its own row of an array. This is the fastest way. Think 2M x 3M array, not a toy size from my post.

Comment: This has got nothing to do with data races; that just makes the problem even worse.  Have each process compute its own result, and send it back to the main thread.  The main thread can do the updates for everyone.

Comment: @FrankYellin True, if you don't care about performance. Copying 2M x 3M array is a lot of overhead.

Comment: What do you think happens when you use a managed list?

Comment: Also.  If you're seriously talking about a 2M x 3M array, you may want to look at numpy.memmap.  This gives you a memory mapped array, backed by a file, that you can share among your processes.

Comment: @FrankYellin "when you use a managed list" - it doesn't have to be a managed list. This was the option I found.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here.  First of all, there is this line of code:

```
pool.map(incr, [a[0], a[1]])
```

The expression `[a[0], a[1]]` creates a *new* list, containing 2 elements a[0] and a[1].  This new list is a new object and is not related to the managed list `a`.  This is one reason why your code isn't working: the managed list is never passed to the child Processes, so whatever you are expecting the managed list to do, it's not going to happen.

What you seem to be trying to do is to increment the individual elements of `a`.  Apparently you would like to do each one of those increments in a separate Process, and somehow use the capability of managed list to keep track of everything.  To do this, your code *must* pass the managed list to the subprocesses.  Therefore `a` must be passed to `incr`.

One approach would be to pass `a` plus an index.  The index would allow `incr` to select one of the nested lists and increment the elements of it.  Here is a possible solution, which does *not* actually work.  It uses the functools.partial method to fix the first argument to incr.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from functools import partial

def incr(a, k):
    print("incr enter", a, k)
    x = a[k]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x[i] += 1
    print("incr exit", a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = mp.Manager()
    a = m.list([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]])
    f = partial(incr, a)
  
    with mp.Pool(2) as pool:
        pool.map(f, range(len(a)))

    print(a)
```

The reason this doesn't work is that the managed list will get updated *when its state changes*, but here you are only changing the state of *one of its items*.  It doesn't make sense to expect the managed list to notice that one its items has changed internally.  That would be impossible to do in general.

To make this script work, you must insert this line

```
a[k] = x
```

after the for loop in incr.  In other words, incr now looks like this:

```
def incr(a, k):
    print("incr enter", a, k)
    x = a[k]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x[i] += 1
    a[k] = x
    print("incr exit", a)
```

This now works as you hoped, since `a[k] = x` changes the state of `a`.

Having said all that, the capabilities of Manager() are not doing you any benefit.  The `map` function already returns an iterator that will collect the results, one at a time, from the subprocesses.  If your goal is to assemble those results into a single list, you would be better off building that list at the end in the main Process.